# Add points to matlibplot scatter plot live

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add points "live" to a scatter plot in matplotlib, so that the points appear on the graph as soon as they are computed. Is it possible? 
If not, is there a python-compatible similar plotting platform where this can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can append new points to the `offsets` array of the return value of `ax.scatter`.

You need to make the plot interactive with `plt.ion()` and update the plot with `fig.canvas.update()`.

This draws from a 2d standard normal distribution and adds the point to the scatter plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plot = ax.scatter([], [])
ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)

while True:
    # get two gaussian random numbers, mean=0, std=1, 2 numbers
    point = np.random.normal(0, 1, 2)
    # get the current points as numpy array with shape  (N, 2)
    array = plot.get_offsets()

    # add the points to the plot
    array = np.append(array, point)
    plot.set_offsets(array)

    # update x and ylim to show all points:
    ax.set_xlim(array[:, 0].min() - 0.5, array[:,0].max() + 0.5)
    ax.set_ylim(array[:, 1].min() - 0.5, array[:, 1].max() + 0.5)
    # update the figure
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: It works. How can I make the graph rescale automatically, though? Thanks!

Comment: How do you can set the color for each of these points? In my case, I have a predefined scatter plot and I'd like to plot the new points with a new color. Thanks.

Comment: there is also `set_color`

Comment: I get this error - 'vertices' must be a 2D list or array with shape Nx2. I am using Python 3. Also getting "too many indices for array" from ax.set_xlim..." line

Comment: I also get the "too many indices for array" error. Changing the 1st append command to `array = np.append(array, [point], axis=0)` fixes this.